# Automatically schedule first run of pipeline

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

While using pipelines, i noticed that the first run of the pipeline needs to be a manual one.Is there a way to automatically trigger the first run of the pipeline.

I created a pipeline source using git integration. I could see pipelines , but had to trigger them manually.My assumption was that they will be triggered after creation of the pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

When a pipeline source is first added, your pipelines are "synced" to the system. This action will not cause any pipeline to be triggered. Similarly when you update your pipelines configuration yaml and push your changes, your pipelines will again "sync" but these changes will not cause any pipeline to be triggered.

Additionally, when you're using a multibranch pipeline source, a "sync" occurs every time a new branch is created, but the pipelines for the new branch will not be triggered.

If you're developing on a new branch locally, and you add some commits, and push your branch for the first time, that action will only cause a sync. It will not trigger a run of the pipeline. In this case, you may need to trigger the pipeline manually or send another commit to produce a commit webhook.

I'd recommend manually creating the branch at the source so that the new branch's pipeline will be created before any new commits are added. Then when you push a new commit to the existing branch, it will cause a run to be triggered.

This behavior isn't explicitly documented but you can read about adding pipeline sources [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Pipeline+Sources#ManagingPipelineSources-AddingaPipelineSource(1.31.0andhigher))

and some information specifically about multibranch pipelines [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Creating+Multibranch+Pipelines)